# Check special character in sql view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

Hi i am in fix for a particular scenario, i have a view which is created by joining multiple tables, the requirement is that i have to find whether the columns in that view will return special character.

```
SELECT SI.ShipmentId,
       CASE
         WHEN SA.AddressType = 1 THEN 'SH'
         ELSE 'CN'
       END AS AddressType,
       SI.Pieces,
       SI.PalletCount,
       SI.Weight,
       SI.UserDescription,
       SI.Class,
       SA.CompanyName,
       SA.Street,
       SA.City,
       SA.State,
       SA.ZipCode,
       CASE
         WHEN SA.Country = 1 THEN 'USA'
         WHEN SA.Country = 2 THEN 'CANADA'
       END AS Country,
       SA.ContactPerson,
       Cast(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(SA.Phone, ')', ''), '(', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') AS VARCHAR(25)) AS Phone,
       S.PoNo,
       S.EstimatedDueDate,
       Cast(S.ShipmentReadyTime AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ShipmentReadyTime,
       Cast(S.ShipmentCloseTime AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ShipmentCloseTime,
       B.BOLNumber,
       S.HazMatEmergencyNo
FROM   CarrierRate.Shipment AS S
       INNER JOIN CarrierRate.BOL AS B
               ON B.ShipmentId = S.ID
       INNER JOIN CarrierRate.ShipmentItems AS SI
               ON SI.ShipmentId = S.ID
       INNER JOIN CarrierRate.ShipmentAddresses AS SA
               ON SA.ShipmentId = S.ID
       INNER JOIN CarrierRate.Carriers AS C
               ON C.ID = S.CarrierId
WHERE  ( SI.AccessorialId = 1 )
       AND ( SA.AddressType IN ( 1, 2 ) )
```

This is that view, i just want to know what all columns will have special character as its data.
For E.g: i have `SA.CompanyName` as one of the column, i have to check whether that column can be filled with special characters?
Please let me know the probable solutions, i am clueless.

Comment: Which special characters are you checking for specifically?

Comment: @Akash:special characters like '!@#*&%' and space also

Comment: Your question is still ambiguous. Do you mean ever? or with the data you currently have in the tables?

Comment: @DwayneTowell: Thats a great question, i want to check ever.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: MsSQL

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the column types of the tables/columns/expressions which contribute to the columns of the view you are interested in. Assuming they are defined as some form of `text` or `varchar` then they CAN contain special characters, **unless** there exists some form of constraint on those columns/tables.

Comment: But how to check individually from query and any idea of how to stop a column for taking those special characters?

Comment: You have to provide the table definitions.